# alSourcePlayv question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to play multiple audio sources using alSourcePlayv. Could someone help me with initialisation of buffers please.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.hollance.com/2011/02/soundbankplayer-using-openal-to-play-musical-instruments-in-your-ios-app/